# Retrieving and editing RRules from existing Fullcalendar event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, rrule

I have a sample website with fullcalendar 5.10 integrated to rrule via the fullcalendar-to-rrule plugin.

I am trying to create a feature that allows users to edit the recurring event, which translates to editing the rrule. However I am having trouble actually accessing the rrule once I add it to the calendar.

I am able to, on eventClick callback, retrieve info.event properties such as the title:

```
function showDateModal(info = null){
  var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('createEventModal'));

  if(info != null)
  {
    document.getElementById('event-title').value = info.event.title;
    //something here should look like 
    //var rrulestart = info.event.rrule.dtstart;
  }
}
```

However I have seen no way to access the rrule info. Especially the "freq" property that I specified when I created the event:

```
calendar.addEvent({
 title: name,
 rrule: { 
   dtstart: date,
   freq: frequency
 },
 allDay: true
});
```

Edited with additional info

Comment: Where is `info` coming from? Is it from the `eventClick` callback, perhaps, at a guess? If so, then that's an individual event, generated as a result of the rrule applied to the ingested event, so logically it's unlikely to contain the rule itself. Also, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object shows that `rrule` isn't a public property of the event in the API, so notwithstanding the above, you'd be unlikely to be able to get it anyway (or at least not without using your JS debugger to dig around inside an event object and seeing if you can find it in an undocumented, internal property).

Comment: If you want to amend a recurrence rule, I think it would probably be more logical to have a separate/additional UI for that, listing all the recurrence rules youv'e got stored (presumably in your database?) and letting the user edit them via that. Or if you do want to do it via a click on an event in the calendar, you'd need a custom property on the event - perhaps an ID which links it to the recurrence rule which caused it to be generated, then you can go and load that info into your modal from the database. That might be a more feasible approach.

Comment: Good points, yes the info is coming from eventClick. 

So I'm gathering that I'm going to have to store the rrule data separately, assign it an ID, and create a custom property on each event which optionally stores the rrule ID used to create it. That's a bit of a bummer, I was hoping it would be more usable out of the box as editing recurring events is pretty standard nowadays.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you can make a feature request to fullCalendar to get better support. The recurring feature existing at all is relatively recent, I think. They only have fairly basic functions for updating individual events at the moment.